# How to change Button label on Search facet (Faceted Search) in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I need to replace Search facet button label which is "Go" by default. Does anyone know how to do that? Actually I need to translate that to another language.

I have tried through text messages but it didn't work.